# DataSet.ReadXML throwing exception about duplicate name

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I have a process that reads the results from a SOAP Web Service. I try to parse the results into a dataset using the ReadXML method and it works as long as there are multiple ship date values. If there is a single ship date value, it throws an exception with the message "Cannot add a column named 'ShipDate': a nested table with the same name already belongs to this DataTable."

affected code:

```
    private ShippingDateResponseMain GetResponse(string rawXml) {
        System.IO.StringReader responseBody = new System.IO.StringReader(rawXml);

        ShippingDateResponseMain response = new ShippingDateResponseMain();

        response.ReadXml(responseBody, System.Data.XmlReadMode.InferSchema);

        return response;
    }
```

good xml:

```
<ShipDateResponse>
  <Customer>
    <Company>FDF</Company>
    <Division>FDF</Division>
    <Department>FDF</Department>
    <Number>024418</Number>
    <CutOffTime>00:00</CutOffTime>
  </Customer>
  <ShipDates>
    <ShipDate>2015-06-04</ShipDate>
    <ShipDate>2015-06-05</ShipDate>
  </ShipDates>
</ShipDateResponse>
```

bad xml:

```
<ShipDateResponse>
  <Customer>
    <Company>FDF</Company>
    <Division>FDF</Division>
    <Department>FDF</Department>
    <Number>024418</Number>
    <CutOffTime>00:00</CutOffTime>
  </Customer>
  <ShipDates>
    <ShipDate>2015-06-04</ShipDate>
  </ShipDates>
</ShipDateResponse>
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why are you reading the XML into a DataSet?  Why not have a custom object that could handle multiple values and parse the XML into that (using, for example, LINQ to XML)?

Comment: I think that i just figured it out by changing the read mode from InferSchema to IgnoreSchema. I am not sure of the ramifications of that changes at this point, but it is not throwing exceptions for the single result or multiple results at this point. Can someone shed some light on the differences there?